# How do I return both char and int in one fprintf statement in C

Tags: c

I want to get a char and check whether if it is Upper or lower case A-Z(return A as 1 to Z as 26) and if it is number 0-9 return the number itself. If not then return the char itself. Im having a hard time to return the char itself from just one printf statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(char c0);

int main(){
    char c;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\n')
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", fun(c));
    }

    return 0;
}
int fun(char c0){
    if(c0 >= '0') {              // check from the the lowest ascii, 0-9.
        if(c0 <= '9') {         // trigger means c0 is 0-9
            return c0-'0';
        }
        else if(c0 <= 'z') {   //check from the highest ascii, a-z
            if(c0 >= 'a') {    //trigger means c0 is a-z
                return c0-'`';
            }
            else if(c0 <= 'Z') {  // check lastly A-Z
                if(c0 >= 'A')
                    return c0-'@';
            }
        }
    }
    return c0;
}
```

**EDIT:** changed some magical numbers and added a while loop.

Comment: Avoid magic numbers. Write `'0'`, not `48`, `'z'`, not `122`, and so on.

Comment: `char` is an integer type, and you are returning a `char` if `c` is not a letter or a digit; what is the problem?

Comment: @David Bowling I am trying to do this program by only 1 printf statment. I don't know how to make c0 returns it's original form(as `char` instead of `int`) when it is not a letter or digit.

Comment: I think that you misunderstand the nature of your problem. `c` is type `char`, which is an integer type. The "original form" of `c0` _is_ an integer, which may represent a character. The problem is that `%d` displays the numeric value. The `%c` conversion specifier would display the character represented by the value returned from `fun()`.

Comment: @David Bowling Yes but how do I do it in one `printf` statment? I want to show the number when they are digit or letter and show the character when they are not. IF I want to use two `printf` statments how do I accomplish it? Do I need to pass a boolean into fun() ?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea to start with. Why does this need to be in one line? Anyway, what about: `fprintf(stdout, fun(c) < 27 ? "%10d\n" : "%c\n", fun(c));`?

Comment: @David Bowling Thanks It works perfectly. Thought firstly what does `fun(c) < 27` part do? Secondly how should I do it with more than 1 line?

Comment: The values from `fun()` are expected to be less than 27 only when an alphanumeric character has been entered, so this is a use of the conditional operator that evaluates to an appropriate format string based on the value returned from `fun()`. Note that the posted code is not portable, since ASCII is not required by the C Standard; this is one reason to favor the portable functions such as `isdigit()`, etc. from `ctype.h`. It would at least be more legible to collect the return value in one line, then choose the format string....

Comment: I should add, it is not strictly portable to rely on ASCII encoding, but you are unlikely to run into other encodings (though it is not unheard of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, the challenge you're running into is that the return value from your function needs to be interpreted as either

- a character value, if it's a letter, or
- a number, if it's a character representing a number.

You can return a single `int` that will hold the result, with the intent that 0 - 9 means "I'm a number" and anything else means "the character with that code," but if so you'll need an if/else statement around your `printf` to determine how that should be printed. I suspect you'll just need to have two different `printf` statements.

Other options include doing things like

- returning a string to print out, though now you need to manage the memory for it, or
- having a *second* function that determines what `printf` specifier to use, which seems really hacky.

On an unrelated note, for readability purposes, don't use ASCII character codes in your program. For what you're doing, the lovely functions `isalpha`, `isdigit`, etc. from `<cctype>` not only do everything you're doing in a more compact way, but they do so more portably, since some (older) systems don't even use ASCII encoding.

Comment: Yes I fully understand I could use `isalpha` and `isdigit`, but Im trying to do it WITHOUT the help of those and wonder if there's a way to straight manipulating the return type through one `printf` statment. ALSO how do I do it with two `prinf` statements ? Do I need to pass a boolean? How do I check the condiction whether I want to `printf` a `char` or an `int`?

Comment: Well, imagine the return value is between 0-9 if it’s a digit character and not in that range if it’s a letter. How could you test this in an if statement?

Comment: Independently, I would strongly advise against coding up your own isalpha or isdigit functions. The real ones use clever tricks like bitvectors and are likely faster than your own. Plus, the resulting code you produce is much harder to read!